# How do I install UglifyCSS?

Tags: software-installation, nodejs, npm

I have uglifyjs, it works great. I want to get uglifycss going, but I'm running into problems.

I don't remember how I installed uglifyjs, but uglifycss wants to use npm.

So I installed npm:

```
apt-get install npm
```

Then installed uglifycss:

```
npm install uglifycss -g
```

And now you're supposed to be able to invoke it with:

```
uglifycss [options] [filename] [...] > output
```

But I get the error:

```
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
```

The command `which uglifycss` produces:

```
/usr/local/bin/uglifycss
```

Invoking it with the full path:

```
/usr/local/bin/uglifycss
```

Produces the same error:

```
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
```

So something isn't quite configured right, but I must have node.js installed and working because uglifyjs depends on it and that one works. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you need to create an alias with:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

for uglifycss to work.